# running macros to a protected sheet - no other answers found

Tags: excel, vba

Here goes...

I have created a project form consisting of 31 Worksheets in the 1 Workbook. 
Worksheet 1, called "NOV Summary", is a summary page. The other 30 worksheets all have various  details placed on them.

The macros that I have created relate to option buttons on the 30 worksheets that when selected place information on the "NOV Summary" page.

This summary page is basically created and filled in automatically as the user enters information on the other sheets. As such, I want to protect the "NOV Summary" page but still have the marcos running.

My vba knowledge is basic at best and I couldn't work it out after all the searching.

Here is an example of the marcos that I am using ---

Sub specifier()

'
' specifier Macro
'
'

```
Sheets("NOV Summary").Select
Range("D4").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Specifier"
With ActiveCell.Characters(Start:=1, Length:=9).Font
    .Name = "Calibri"
    .FontStyle = "Regular"
    .Size = 11
    .Strikethrough = False
    .Superscript = False
    .Subscript = False
    .OutlineFont = False
    .Shadow = False
    .Underline = xlUnderlineStyleNone
    .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorLight1
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .ThemeFont = xlThemeFontMinor
End With
Range("D4").Select
Sheets("PR1311001").Select
```

End Sub

If you could help with placing the correct code to allow this to happen it would be greatly appreciated!

Mnay thanks

Tom

Answer (score 4):

You can unprotect the sheet prior to running the macro and then protect it again afterwards

```
Public Sub PasswordTest()


Dim password As String
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = Sheet1

password = "password123"

'Check if sheet is protected
If ws.ProtectContents Then

    ws.Unprotect password

End If

         '*******
         'put your code here
         '*******

'Protect sheet again
ws.Protect password


Exit Sub

'error handling block
err:

MsgBox err.Description, "an error occured"

'if the sheet isn't protected then we should protect it again.
If ws.ProtectContents = False Then

    ws.Protect password

End If


End Sub
```

---

As pointed out in the comments, you can set the `UserInterFaceOnly` parameter when you're protecting your sheet. This will protect it but allow the macro to still work on it.

```
ws.Protect Password:=password, UserInterFaceOnly:=True
```

You can read about it here..

http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/excel-macro-protected-sheet.htm

Comment: + 1 Another tip ;) You don't need to protect/unprotect the sheet everytime. See the property [UserInterfaceOnly](http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/excel-macro-protected-sheet.htm)

Comment: Yes that is a good tip. I did know about that one, but I've used it before and it's caused me issues when the sheet has been manually unprotected and then protected again not through the code.

Comment: @SiddharthRout I added some information to the answer, to make it more complete. Thanks for the pointer.

Comment: Thanks! I have tried both options but the following Run time message has appeared, not a clue why ---- error '1004' Unable to set the name property of the font class'.


I haven't changed anything and it doesn't have this error if I take out the above codes
Sorry to be a pain but any ideas as to why?
Thanks again

Comment: @TomIrish15 ok...Do you unprotect the sheet right at the top of your code? is the sheet protected or unprotected when you hit the error?

Comment: Yep, changed that. I didn't change my original macro, which is where the run-time error is coming from. Selecting debug highlights the .Name = "Calibri" section on my macro

Comment: Try unprotecting your sheet at the top of your original macro (it may have issues running if the sheet is protected.

Comment: yea I have that there. The sheet is unprotected when it hits the error as far as I can see.

Comment: put in `msgbox ActiveSheet.ProtectContents` on the line before you hit the error and see what you get back (true or false), replace `Activesheet` with whichever sheet you're working with... I think that your sheet is protected...

Comment: did you make sure to change the sheet reference to the sheet that you want unlocking `Set ws = Sheet1` my code was set to work on `Sheet1` only.. (just trying all the simple stuff first :))

Comment: Its only Sheet1  that I need it to work on, didnt need to change that part. Ha I dont blame you... Basic at best was not a lie!

Comment: If true comes back... then the sheet is protected... Add the `ws.Unprotect password` bit into your macro just before the msgbox line you just added.....

Comment: Perhaps I should give up on this! Put that in and run-time 424 Object Required pops up this time. Placed the ws.Unprotect bit the line above the msgbox line....

Comment: have you declared your sheet as `ws` or is it something else.. ie `Sheet1.Protect.... ` or `Worksheets("sheet_name").Protect....`

Comment: Sam, sorry for the delayed response. Been having a look over it when I could and have started again basically, get out the little errors. With your above help I now have it running fine. No errors!! So many thanks for the help with this..... got there in the end!

Comment: @TomIrish15 good news.. Thanks for letting me know.. Could you accept the answer if it worked for you please?